# pgfplots externalize with hyperref

Tags: pgfplots, hyperref, cross-referencing, tikz-external

I'm using pgfplots with externalize because my document has a lot of plots which causes problems with memory limitation in LaTeX. In one of my plots I have a reference to an equation. In the file main-figure0.pdf the reference shows up correclty with the hypertext link from the hyperref package. But the hypertext link doesn't show up in the main.pdf file.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-shell-escape]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a=b
    \label{eq}
\end{equation}
\ref{eq}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, rectangle] (block) at (0,0) {\ref{eq}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{test1}
    \label{fig:test1}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I compile with:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -src-specials main.tex
pdflatex -shell-escape -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input {main}"
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -src-specials main.tex
```

How do I get the hypertext link to show up in the actual document?

Comment: If only one plot has that issue, you can disable the externalization for this one plot.

Comment: I suppose importing hyperlinks by means of an external graphics is unsupported, sorry. Perhaps The comment of @T.Verron should become the answer.

Comment: Thank you @T.Verron. I guess I can live with your solution although it's only some sort of workaround. Could you please make your comment to an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. `;)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `tikz` imports external graphics as pictures, just like what you would do with `\includegraphics`. Hypertext links are indeed dropped.

If only a few plots include hypertext links, as a workaround, you can disable the externalization for these plots, by adding

```
\tikzset{external/export next=false}
```

before each of them.

Comment: Awesome workaround the hyperref + external + `\ref \label` situation!